# Translation of "has" in certain scenario

Tags: перевод

How do you translate a sentence like: "Everything here has a lot of sugar" when talking about a food product containing some ingredient. I assume "Здесь у всего много сахара" makes no sense and there is a separate syntax for saying "has" in a case like this where the subject in question *contains* the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Literal translation doesn't always yield proper usage.

```
здесь во всём много сахара
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you could use `содержит` - a literal translation of `contains`:

> Здесь все содержит много сахара.

Comment: Theoretically, yes, but I find it somewhat hard to imagine anyone using `содержит` in a real-world conversation. At least if sugar is the substance in question, rather than something with a sciencey name.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be translated as: "Во всём этом содержится много сахара"

Answer (score 0):

If about country in common or if you're surrounded by shelves in a supermarket:

Здесь/тут везде всё с сахаром.

If you're holding a bun or a cookie you can say:

Здесь/тут слишком много сахара.

or as mentioned above:

Здесь все содержит много сахара.